# SQL Server VIEW results different to the SELECT

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, view

I have created the following simple view:

```
CREATE VIEW cs.MyTestPO AS
SELECT ttdpur401100.t_orno
, ttdpur401100.t_item
, ttcibd001100.t_dsca
FROM ttdpur401100 
    JOIN ttcibd001100 ON ttcibd001100.t_item = ttdpur401100.t_item
```

Then `SELECT * FROM cs.MyTestPO` returns 276376 rows

If I run the select statement by itself

```
SELECT ttdpur401100.t_orno
, ttdpur401100.t_item
, ttcibd001100.t_dsca
FROM ttdpur401100 
     JOIN ttcibd001100 ON ttcibd001100.t_item = ttdpur401100.t_item
```

it returns 277488 rows

Can anyone suggest why the view is missing 1112 rows that the SELECT statement returns.

Comment: Is it possible that 1112 rows were added after you selected the data from the view, but before you selected from the query?

Comment: The Select from the view and the Select were run directly after one another several times and produced the same result.

Comment: Put them inside a transaction and run again with DISTINCT on the result set. I'm guessing the view is enforcing uniqueness.

Comment: why would duplicates in the primary table create the result? I did a count on the primary key in the tdpur401100 table and there are no duplicates.

Comment: Is everything in the `cs` schema? If not, is there a possibility of some tables duplicated between the `cs` and `dbo` schemas, such that you're querying different tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to see the differences between the sets, try

```
SELECT d
d.t_orno    , d.t_item    , c.t_dsca
FROM ttdpur401100 d
   inner  JOIN ttcibd001100 c ON 
c.t_item = d.t_item left outer join
cs.MyTestPO t on d.t_item = t.t_item
where
t.t_item is null
```

Comment: I've identified the missing rows from the view but I can't see any reason for them to be excluded from the select from view results. Is there anything I should be checking?

Comment: check the row count on table c- does it match the view or the select row count?

Comment: Table c does not have the same row count as the view or the select row count. But so what?

Comment: When you look at some of the 1112 rows the view is missing, do you notice anything distinctive about them, like that they're duplicates, or are they rows the view 'should' return?  I should have said to check the row count on 'd inner join c,' which should match your 'select stmt by itself' count.

Comment: also, are you sure you're querying the same source each time?  that you're not running the select statement against a different db than the one the view is in?

Comment: Hi - yes the problem is that the view was not joining to the same table as the Select. There is a table with the same name in cs schema and the default dbo schema.

Answer (score 7):

If there is truly a difference between selecting from a view and running its definition ad-hoc, I would:

- Run [sp_refreshview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187821.aspx)
- Run [dbcc checkdb](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx)
- Drop and recreate the view
- Make sure SQL is patched up to the [most recent service pack](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/ff803383.aspx).
- ~~~~~Probably a lot of other steps that an MVP would think of go here~~~~~
- Restart the SQL Server instance (we're starting to reach, now)?
- Reboot the server?
- Contact [support services](http://support.microsoft.com/ph/1044/en-us) (this would be getting serious).

It would be interesting to see if there's a difference in execution plans, statistics io, etc. before doing any of this, though.

Comment: We have a restart scheduled on a couple of days so I'll check again after that.

Comment: Did sp_refreshview not do anything? As always, use at your own risk, but I wouldn't hesitate to run that on a production box (try test first), especially if I'm getting bad data anyway.

Comment: No - I DROP'd the VIEW and re-created it. I presumed that would have more impact?

Answer (score 0):

Just had the same issue with a SQL2008 instance.  When I right-clicked and scripted my view, as create, I could clearly see a hard-coded value in the view definition as 'A'.  However, when I right-clicked and selected the top 1000 rows the hard-code was not being returned.  Seemingly, an entirely different set of code was being executed.  Bizarre!  Defies everything I've ever known about a database.  Must be some odd bug in the guts of SQL Server, or weird data cache retrieval despite the view being modified...  No windows functions, no transactions involved...  I'm working against a static set of data for a data migration, not a live system.

When I UNION the view definition with the select TOP 1000 from the view I get an error about mismatching columns definitions, so obviously something's out-of-sync.

I recompiled the view and the issue went away.